# PIP fails installing pylint

Tags: python, installation, pip, pylint

I have been using spyder for last three years, and just moved on to Visual Studio Code.

VSC is recommending me to install pylint, but my cmd outputs this.

```
    C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install pylint
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\newsk\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 188, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\newsk\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 185, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "c:\users\newsk\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 332, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "c:\users\newsk\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 179, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "c:\users\newsk\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 362, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "c:\users\newsk\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 313, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self._populate_link(req)
  File "c:\users\newsk\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 279, in _populate_link
    req.link = self.finder.find_requirement(req, upgrade)
  File "c:\users\newsk\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 900, in find_requirement
    best_candidate_result = self.find_best_candidate(
  File "c:\users\newsk\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 883, in find_best_candidate
    candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
  File "c:\users\newsk\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 827, in find_all_candidates
    package_links = self.process_project_url(
  File "c:\users\newsk\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 792, in process_project_url
    html_page = self._link_collector.fetch_page(project_url)
  File "c:\users\newsk\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 612, in fetch_page
    return _get_html_page(location, session=self.session)
  File "c:\users\newsk\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 451, in _get_html_page
    resp = _get_html_response(url, session=session)
  File "c:\users\newsk\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 149, in _get_html_response
    resp = session.get(
  File "c:\users\newsk\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 543, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\newsk\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\session.py", line 421, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\newsk\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 520, in request
    settings = self.merge_environment_settings(
  File "c:\users\newsk\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 697, in merge_environment_settings
    env_proxies = get_environ_proxies(url, no_proxy=no_proxy)
  File "c:\users\newsk\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 766, in get_environ_proxies
    if should_bypass_proxies(url, no_proxy=no_proxy):
  File "c:\users\newsk\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 750, in should_bypass_proxies
    bypass = proxy_bypass(parsed.hostname)
  File "c:\users\newsk\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 96, in proxy_bypass
    return proxy_bypass_registry(host)
  File "c:\users\newsk\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 61, in proxy_bypass_registry
    proxyEnable = int(winreg.QueryValueEx(internetSettings,
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I had a similar message  last time when I tried to install tensorflow using pip.

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please mention the pip version you are using...
You can find it by using the `pip --version`

Comment: If you are using pip's older versions, try using `pip3 install <module_name>`

Comment: It says my pip version is '20.1.1'

Comment: I figured it out! Pylint proceeded installation as I changed my proxy settings. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: glad you figured out :D